# Asignar valores alrededor de dummy

Tags: python

Amigos,

Necesito asignar valores 1 a los x valores alrededor (digamos x=2) de una dummy pre-asignada. Tengo un df de la siguiente forma:

```
dummy
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
...
```

Necesito el siguiente ouput:

```
dummy dummy_out
0      0
0      0
0      1  # x-2
0      1  # x-1
1      1  # x
0      1  # x+1
0      1  # x+2
0      0
0      1
0      1
1      1
0      1
0      1
0      0
...
```

He intentado hacerlo con una condición, pero es muy agobiante cuando x es muy grande, además de funcionar solo para las observaciones anteriores a "x".

```
df['dummy_out'] = 0
df['dummy_out'] = np.where(df['dummy']==1,1,df['dummy_out'])
df['dummy_out'] = np.where(df['dummy']==1,df['dummy_out'].shift(1)==1,df['dummy_out'])
df['dummy_out'] = np.where(df['dummy']==1,df['dummy_out'].shift(2)==1,df['dummy_out'])
```

Alguna idea de como hacer esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finalmente lo siguiente logró el cometido:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"d":     (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
                   "range": (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)})
    
v = (df[df['d']==1].index.values)[0]
for i in v:
    df.loc[i-2:i+2,'range'] = 1
```